# Problem with setting visibility of cardView in recyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, visibility, android-cardview

Hello I have a problem with setting the visibility of the `cardView` part.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout(..........)>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        (..........)>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/titleLayout"
            (..........)>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_title"
                (..........)/>

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
                android:visibility="gone" <<<<<<<<<
                android:id="@+id/expandableView"
                (..........)>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_description"
                    (..........) />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_view_priority"
                   (..........) />

            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How you can see I divided the `cardView` into two parts. In my `showDescription()` method I want to change the visibility of description section to visible or (if it's already visible) to gone.

```
View cardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.note_item, container, false);
        final ConstraintLayout expandableView = cardView.findViewById(R.id.expandableView);

        adapter.setOnItemClickListener(new NoteAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot, int position) {

                Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);
                int pathInt = position;
                String path =String.valueOf(pathInt);
                showDescription(expandableView);
            }
        });
        return RootView;
    }
    public void showDescription (ConstraintLayout expandableView){
        if(expandableView.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){
            expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else {
            expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why but after click on `cardView` (no matter which one) nothing happens. Maybe it's since my app don't know on witch `cardView` execute that method ? How I can make it works ?

Comment: Do not name views the same name convention as other views - Instead of calling your view `CardView`, call it `cardView` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
final ConstraintLayout expandableView = cardView.findViewById(R.id.expandableView);
```

You are making your `expandableView` `final`. `final` variable can not be modified. Remove the `final` keyword:

```
ConstraintLayout expandableView = cardView.findViewById(R.id.expandableView);
```

I think also you should place your `showDescription` function's code inside `setOnItemClickListener` instead of passing `expandableView' to a function.